# How to POST JSON using Adobe Flex

Tags: json, actionscript-3, apache-flex, http, post

I'm trying to POST some JSON data using Adobe Flex but having some problems.  I'm now getting the error message "A URL must be specified with useProxy set to false", even though I do have useProxy set to false.

Update : code below is now working.

```
                var data:Object = new Object();
                data.ipaddr = ipaddr.text;
                data.netmask = netmask.text;
                data.gatewayip = gatewayip.text;
                var jsonData:String = JSON.stringify(data);
                var s:mx.rpc.http.HTTPService = new mx.rpc.http.HTTPService();
                // URL needs to be specified on a separate line, call is unreliable otherwise
                s.url = Utils.getBaseURL() + '/cgi-bin/setnetworksettings';
                s.contentType = "application/json";
                s.resultFormat = mx.rpc.http.HTTPService.RESULT_FORMAT_TEXT;
                s.method = "POST";
                s.useProxy = false;
                s.addEventListener("result", httpResult);
                s.addEventListener("fault", httpFault);         
                s.send(jsonData);
```

Comment: i have no experience n adobe flex but i hope this urrl can help you, http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2006/03/28/tutorial-using-json-with-flex-2-and-actionscript-3/

Comment: s.send(JSON.encode(..yourObject..));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "**doesn't seem to do anything**"? No response from the server? Fault instead of result? Which one? Help us help you with more details, just stating *it doesn't work* is not enough.

First of all, be sure that your URL is correct, you should get something in the service result handler OR fault handler, anything. That should help you diagnose and fix any URL problems if any.

Then for the JSON part, you object is not a valid JSON (no escaping and `:` instead of `=`), try sending this first: `{"ipaddr":"10.1.1.1"}`.
From here it should be easy: as F4L stated, you can use the JSON class to encode a real object directly to JSON.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful.  I replaced my erred raw JSON with a call to the JSON encoder.  My fault handler now seems to indicate that useProxy should be false, even though I do have it set to false in the new code.

Comment: Looks like I have it working now.  I moved the url specification to a separate line and that solved the useProxy problem.  Thanks guys.